# Write a list of group members to sheet google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to write a list of all the members of a group within a google domain to a google sheet. I found this script on googles forums but I do not want the results to go to a log I want them to go to the active spreedsheet. Can anyone explain how to do this?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#getUsers()

```
function listGroupMembers() {
  var GROUP_EMAIL = "example@googlegroups.com";
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
  var users = group.getUsers();
  var str = "Group " + GROUP_EMAIL + " has " + users.length +
  " members: ";
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    str = str + user.getEmail() + ", ";
  }
  Logger.log(str);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. You put me on the right path. For anyone who visits this page looking for the same answer here is what I came up with.

```
function listGroupMembers() {
  var GROUP_EMAIL = "groups@google.com";
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
  var users = group.getUsers();
  var str ="";
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    str = str + user.getEmail() + ", " + "\n";
  }
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1);
range.setValue(str);
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(str);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);


}
```